# . Can't perform callout when resuming a flow or inside an Apex Queueable

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method, external-services

Currently, I've setup a scheduled flow to make an external callout. If i debug manually it's working successfully because it's firing for a single record. But if i scheduled the flow I'm getting below exception.

> Error element Get_Prospect_Fetch_User_Details (FlowActionCall).
> Callout failed for invocable action
> GetProspectLinkedinUserExternalService.getPublicV1InsightsContact.
> Can't perform callout when resuming a flow or inside an Apex
> Queueable. Place the callout to External Services invocable actions
> before pausing a flow or scheduling an Apex queueable. For more
> information, contact your Salesforce administrator.

My flow:
[image]

I'm not sure how to handle this issue

Comment: Might be that you are performing DML and then callout in the same transaction ? You need to perform Callout in the future method and call that future method in invocable method so your callout and DML will be in different transactions. See [related](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing_dml.htm)